# glClear: RAM usage slighty increasing

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

Following is my little opengl program, just drawing a triangle. There is an glitch, the RAM is slightly increasing by about 10K per second the moment i add the glClear() function. Why is that so?

```
int screenwidth=537, screenheight=716;
GLFWwindow* window;

if (!glfwInit()) return -1;

window = glfwCreateWindow(screenwidth, screenheight, "Test", NULL, NULL);
if(!window){glfwTerminate(); return -1;}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

//Setting up the OpenGL Context
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, screenwidth, screenheight, 0, 0, 1);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glClearColor(1,0.9176f,0.1259f,1);

//The rendering loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(.5f, .5f);
    glVertex2f(0, .5f);
    glEnd();

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS){
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOxyaxuTsyI

Comment: You have a memory leak in the code you're not showing.

Comment: Ok, i've added the rest of the code.

Comment: So now i've tried different things:

1. using GLUT instead of GLFW with the following example: http://openglsamples.sourceforge.net/triangle.html and i got the same problem

2. instead of using glClear im now drawing a triangle strip for the background and i don't have the RAM problem any more.

To explain my problem further, i've added a link to a video showcasing my example programm and the problem.